# Using MixedReality.WebRTC.UWP in a WinForm App

Tags: uwp, webrtc, windows-mixed-reality, uwp-c#

Is it possible to use the `Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC.UWP` library in a legacy C# WinForm Application, built with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and Visual Studio 2017?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to use the Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC.UWP library in a legacy C# WinForm Application.

I'm afraid, you can't use `Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC.UWP` library in a legacy C# `WinForm` Application. For your requirement, the better way is use .NET Core 3.0 to create a C# Desktop application then install `Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC` nuget package.  For more detail please refer this [document](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC#user-manual).

Comment: Yes, I have been looking over those references, but was concerned about the line in the tutorial stating, that there is 'currently no simple solution to display raw video frames from a .NET Core application, like there is with UWP'.  Would you happen to have a reference to an appropriate implementation for displaying the video frames?

Comment: displaying the video frames? could you show more detail about it.

Comment: The UWP tutorial describes using the I420RemoteVideoFrameReady delegate to send frame data to a [VideoBridge class] (https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC/blob/master/examples/TestAppUwp/Video/VideoBridge.cs), which feeds the data to a Media Foundation video sink.  The .NET Core tutorial doesn't offer any steps for this part of the solution.